# symfony2:How to selection one field to view using formType table

Tags: ajax, symfony

I want to show one field using ajax for edit this field but i have in my formtype all fields of table 
this my formtype

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $options = array('multiple' => 'multiple');
        $builder
                ->add('name', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'Company Name',
                ))
                ->add('abbreviation', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'label' => 'Abbreviation',
                ))
                ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('city', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('address', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('facebook', 'url', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('linkedin', 'url', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('twitter', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('youtube', 'url', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('googleplus', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('skype', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('chairman', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('managingdirector', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('contactperson', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('contactpersontitle', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('contactpersonphone', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('isActivated', 'checkbox', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('countryId', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Country',
                    'class' => 'Custom\CMSBundle\Entity\Country',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                    }
                ))
                ->add('owner')
                ->add('class')
                ->add('level', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        '1' => '1',
                        '2' => '2',
                        '3' => '3',
                        '4' => '4',
                        '5' => '5',
                        '6' => '6',
                        '7' => '7',
                        '8' => '8',
                        '9' => '9',
                        '10' => '10',
                    )
                ))
                ->add('phonechairman', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('mobilechairman', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('faxchairman', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('emailchairman', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('phonemanagingdirector', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('mobilemanagingdirector', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('faxmanagingdirector', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ))
                ->add('emailmanagingdirector', 'text', array(
                    'required' => false,
                ));
    }
```

how can i return form edit for one field using ajax
If the answer hide the field, How can i set the field that not hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which field you want to edit by Ajax, but suppose it's "name".
And suppose your entity is Entity1 (Entity1.php like User.php is an entity).

Then you have to create a specific editForm for this use case.
Example : editEntity1Form1 (choose the best name)

Then editEntity1Form1 will have :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $options = array('multiple' => 'multiple');
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Company Name',
            ));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 * It specifies the entity corresponding to your editing form
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'DIRECTORY_TO_YOUR_ENTITY\Entity1'
    ));
}
```

Now in your controller, you'll have to speficy in your ajax edit Action that you use EditEntity1Form1 :

```
/**
* Creates a form to edit an Entity1 entity.
*
* @param Entity1 $entity The entity
* your_form_route_name_here is the route name of the action you want to associate to your edit form (if you submit your edit form, it will make a post with this route. But you can get this action route in you twig view and Post it in an ajax way as you want.
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(Entity1 $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new EditEntity1Form1(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('your_form_route_name_here', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    return $form;
}
```

and for your controller you can have a look to : http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/01/19/symfony-2-forms-and-ajax/

in your ajax POST action you will have these lines :

```
 $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
 $form->handleRequest($request);
```

These lines specify to use your editEntity1Form1.
$entity is got by something like :

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('YOURBundle:Entity1')->find($id);
```

Where $id is passed to your post ajax action.

Comment: This answer very long
i want create from for single field automatically

Comment: in fact in your case you need to have a form with only one $builder->add(....) for the field you need. The other fields will not be required.

Comment: then maybe I should cut my answer after the first code portion